# CSS not applying when url is "example.php/1/2"

Tags: javascript, php, css, routes

I am doing a site, a blogplatform, where I would like to get info based on the get.
So I wanna show a specific post if the url is "post.php/1/2" where the 1 is the user-id, and 2 is the post-id. When I do this, my php-file doesnt find the js nor the css file. I get this error:

"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:" and I get a syntax error for my Javascript, saying "unexpected <". But It works fine on other sites.

I am sorry for describing a bit bad, I hope you understand. Otherwise I'll explain better!

EDIT: Gotta be some routing problem. If I go on "post.php" it works fine, but "post.php/" is troublesome.

Comment: can you share your link or code you have tried?

Comment: At the moment, I only have  **$request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));**.
I also have some html, like an <ul> for the navigator, but the only PHP-code I have is that.

Comment: Please _update the question_ with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using relative paths and get a 404 (or other html page) instead of your desired css/js file.

So try using absolute paths (begin path with / and not ../) like: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css">`

and not 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/main.css">`

Comment: This worked. I had a 404 error first, but it fixed when I remembered to write down which folder it's inside. Thanks!